# HRV background observer for HealthKit never triggers (react native)

Tags: react-native, observer-pattern, healthkit

I'm working on a React-Native app that on the iOS side collects HRV readings from HealthKit, I need to mount an observer that triggers when new HRV readings are added to HealthKit. I also need it to trigger when the app I terminated.
I understand that the observer will first trigger when the phone is unlocked and that is not a problem the data collection is not very time-sensitive but needs to be automatically done.

Relevant dependencies:

```json
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-native-health": "^1.7.2"
```

How I mount the observer

```js
useEffect(() => {
  new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.AppleHealthKit).addListener(
    'healthKit:HeartRateVariabilitySDNN:new',
    async () => {
      getDataForObserver()
    },
  );
});
```

So far my observer doesn't seem to mount under any circumstances and newer triggers when the app I terminated, I have crashlytics to record errors on the method but that also never triggers. I hope someone can help figure out why my observer isn't mounting. I hope mounting is the right word.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure of this but, it might be beacuse your callback is an async function, you can switch it to: (Also you forgot to add the brackets at the end)

```
useEffect(() => {
  new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.AppleHealthKit).addListener(
    'healthKit:HeartRateVariabilitySDNN:new',
    () => {
      getDataForObserver().then(()=>console.log('Success at fetching observed data'))
    },
  );
}, []);
```

Comment: *"beacuse your callback is an async function"* how do you know that?

Comment: at the beginning of the arrow function it has an async `async () => `

Comment: This does not mean that `getDataForObserver` is async..

Comment: you're right! I just wrongfully assumed!